# coldbox event.setView method not working as expected with module attribute

Tags: coldbox

I am new to ColdBox so please be understanding :)

In the [documentation](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Layouts-Views.cfm#Views_From_A_Module) I found the option of setting a view from an external module in coldbox, by providing the "module" attribute.

When in my controller I set for example `event.setView (view="test_view", module="contentbox");` I get the following error:

```
Application Execution Exception
Error Type: missinginclude : 0
Error Messages: Page //views/test_view.cfm [C:\(...path...)\slawek_contentbox\views\test_view.cfm] not found
```

It seems like coldbox is ignoring the module setting and is looking in the main views path `\views\`, but I would expect it to look inside `\modules\contentbox\views\`.

I would really appreciate if anyone would be able to help me with this issue!

Comment: edit: if I set view="modules/contentbox/test_view" it works fine, but in that case why the module parameter anyway?

Comment: edit 2: OK, I think I finally got it! The framework first looks into the module in the folder which is specified in settings to be the folder containing views (in ModuleConfig.cfc the viewsLocation convention is set to the appropriate directory). In contentbox which I am digging into it was set to 'layouts' that's why the default path where the views were expected was /modules/contentbox/layouts and not /modules/contentbox/views is I initially expected.